# Java Persistence EntityNotFound Exception on an Object with Embedded Compound PK

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, persistence

I'm having some issues with Java Persistence. I've already searched for some answers, and found one where the issue was that a field that could be null was not set to nullable = true. However, that did not seem to work for me.

I will change some names, but try and keep it explained.

This is the exception:
EJB Exception: ; nested exception is: javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find PersistedObject with id PersistedObjectPK@ec2736; nested exception is: javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find PersistedObject  with id PersistedObjectPK@ec2736

The PersistedObject itself has a Primary Key that is defined as an embedded object with a Compount Primary Key.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DB_TABLE_NAME", schema = "SCHEMA")
public class PersistedObject implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5823302417440143578L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private PersistedObjectPK id;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_POTATO", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private AnotherPersistedObject anotherPersistedObject;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "ID_CABBAGE", referencedColumnName = "ID_POTATO", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "CT_CARROT", referencedColumnName = "CT_LETTUCE", insertable = false, updatable = false) })
    private OtherPersistedObject otherPersistedObject;
```

The PersistedObjectPK Class is as follows:

```
@Embeddable
public class PersistedObjectPK implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4118584598667509460L;

    @Column(name = "ID_POTATO")
    private long idLaudo;

    @Column(name = "ID_CABBAGE")
    private long idTermoApreensao;

    @Column(name = "CT_CARROT")
    private long ctProduto;
```

I've already debugged it, the query runs fine directly in the database.
But I cannot find what is causing this error. 
The error happens during the Merge operation, after the system requests for the changes to be saved.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue.

During the save to database operation.

```
        AnotherPersistedObject term;
            //Previously, it did not do thi, it tried saving with the list, then clean and re-insert it.
                    List<PersistedObject > persistedObjects = term.getList();
                    term.setList(null);
            //After this change, it is now working as excpeted
                    this.getGenericBO().save(AnotherPersistedObject.class, term, term.getId());
                    term.setList(persistedObjects);
                    deleteList(term);
                    saveList(term);
```